# BigQuery - Populating SELECT fields from results of a temp function

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I have a query that has the same field name appearing multiple times in various join subqueries. I would like to abstract out this field name into a temporary function such that it will amend it in all places if I change it within the function only.

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM

(SELECT field1, COUNT(*) sq1_total
FROM table
WHERE condition = 1
GROUP BY field 1) sq1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT field1, COUNT(*) sq2_total
FROM table
WHERE condition = 0
GROUP BY field 1) sq2

USING(field1)
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION replace_field_name() AS (...);

SELECT *
FROM

(SELECT replace_field_name(), COUNT(*) sq1_total
FROM table
WHERE condition = 1
GROUP BY replace_field_name()) sq1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT replace_field_name(), COUNT(*) sq2_total
FROM table
WHERE condition = 0
GROUP BY replace_field_name()) sq2

USING(replace_field_name())
```

So that when I want to compare many different fields like this, I only need to change the field name in one place as opposed to five places.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't do this without using dynamic SQL (which I'm not sure BigQuery even supports).  The column name can't be given using a literal, or the result of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below thoughts/proposals relevant in terms of BigQuery Standard SQL

> I would like to abstract out this field name into a temporary function ...

As Tim mentioned in his comment - it is quite not possible to do in a way you mock it

> I want to compare many different fields like this, I only need to change the field name in one place as opposed to five places.

You can try to re-write your query in such a way that you will need to change field name in less places, like in below examples

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT field1, COUNT(*) sq1_total FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE condition = 1 GROUP BY 1) sq1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT field1, COUNT(*) sq2_total FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE condition = 0 GROUP BY 1) sq2
USING (field1)
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT field1, 
  COUNTIF(condition = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY field1) sq1_total, 
  COUNTIF(condition = 0) OVER(PARTITION BY field1) sq2_total
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

In bothe above queries - there are "just" three place to replace field name in (as opposed to 5 in original query)

**Obviously** - this does not address the problem in qualitative way - just quantitatively

> Is this possible?

Good news  - there is always work around - but usually it requires to slightly change something in your requirements, expectations

For example in below solution you need to set field name only once!!! in `UNNEST(['field1']) field` line

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT field, value,
  COUNTIF(condition = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY field, value) sq1_total, 
  COUNTIF(condition = 0) OVER(PARTITION BY field, value) sq2_total
FROM (
  SELECT field, REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, CONCAT(r'"', field, '":"?([^",])"?')) value, condition
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST([TO_JSON_STRING(t)]) x,
  UNNEST(['field1']) field
)
```

the "price" is - you will have output in form of (with dummy data)

```
Row field   value   sq1_total   sq2_total    
1   field1  1       1           3    
2   field1  2       1           0
```

instead of output from original query

```
Row field1  sq1_total   sq2_total    
1   1       1           3    
2   2       1           null
```

> I want to compare many different fields like this ...

The **extra value** in above approach is that you can run your comparison (for as many fields as you want) in one shot - by adding needed fields' names into `UNNEST(['field1']) field` list as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT field, value,
  COUNTIF(condition = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY field, value) sq1_total, 
  COUNTIF(condition = 0) OVER(PARTITION BY field, value) sq2_total
FROM (
  SELECT  field, REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, CONCAT(r'"', field, '":"?([^",])"?')) value, condition
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST([TO_JSON_STRING(t)]) x,
  UNNEST(['field1', 'field2']) field
)
-- ORDER BY field, value
```

so result could look like

```
Row field   value   sq1_total   sq2_total    
1   field1  1       1           3    
2   field1  2       1           0    
3   field2  1       1           1    
4   field2  2       0           2    
5   field2  3       1           0
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that will solve my problem nicely :)

Comment: glad to hear this. love to solve something that from first glace looks like not solvable :o) but ends up being relatively simple